# Apollo GraphQL - trying to filter results from Neo4j server ends up resulting in null value

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo

I was doing some experimentation with GraphQL and Neo4j and had the following queries and type definitions:

```
query GetUsers {
  users {
    id
    email
    name
  }
}
query GetUserByID {
  user(id: "example_id") {
    id
    name
    email
  }
}

==========================================

type User @node(label: User) {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  user(id: ID!): User
  users: [User]
}
```

When I run the GetUsers query, I get the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "example_id",
        "email": "example_email@gmail.com",
        "name": "John Doe"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, when I run the GetUserByID query, I get the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": null
  }
}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You miss the user id:  user(id: "example_id")

Comment: please show the resolver code for `user`

Comment: My resolver:

module.exports.resolvers = {
    Query: {
        user(parent, args, context, info) {
            const { id } = args;
            return context.db.Users.find((a) => a.id == id)
        },
    },
};

Comment: As a friendly tip (in case you don't know already), check out the GraphQL library for Neo4j (JS based): https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/getting-started/